# How to write exact values for points on line graphs?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

objects = ('A', 'B', 'C')
avgA, avgB, avgC = 0.009990256984352774, 0.0014206548643907065, 0.055161861569464204
performance = [avgA, avgB, avgC]
exact = plt.plot(performance, alpha=0.5, color= 'purple')
plt.xlabel('Compression Method')
plt.ylabel('Average Distance b/w Uncompressed & Compressed Point')
plt.title('Evaluation of Different Compression Methods - Averages')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

There are 3 issues with my graph:

1. I'd like the X axis labels to be A, B & C instead of 0.0 ,1.0 & 2.0. The values on y-axis are correct.
2. How can I display the **exact value on my line graph for A/B/C?** For instance, A on the x axis corresponds to 0.00999 on the y axis but on the graph the exact value isn't written anywhere. Like in bar charts we can write values on top of the bar. Can we do so for line graphs?
3. Also, how can I **improve the scale**? Currently, my graph displays y axis values from 0.0 to 0.5 but I want to make it **more precise**.
   [image]

Comment: What do you mean by exact value? The value of what? And what do you mean by more precise?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Please see the edited qs. I added an image of my current plot and updated the question.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add more ticks to the y axis?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes but that's one of the problems

Comment: @JohanC:  A:  0.009990256984352774
B: 0.0014206548643907065
C: 0.055161861569464204

Comment: @JohanC I just realized xticks wasn't making any difference to the plot so I removed it. And yes, I was missing out objects from plt.plot() so the x-axis label problem is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the xticks, best to just call `plot` with `objects` as its first parameter. To set more yticks, `MultipleLocator` can be used to indicate the distance between the major and the minor ticks (the major ticks display a number).

To add text to the plot, just call `plt.annotate('text', xy=(x,y))` where the x goes 0, 1, 2 as the x are just labels. The y is the usual y-value.
You can add many option to position the text, with or without arrow, aligning etc. See the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

avgA, avgB, avgC = 0.009990256984352774, 0.0014206548643907065, 0.055161861569464204
objects = ('A', 'B', 'C')
performance = [avgA, avgB, avgC]
plt.plot(objects, performance, alpha=0.5, color= 'purple')
plt.plot(objects, performance, color= 'dodgerblue', marker='o')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.005))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.001))
for i, avg in enumerate(performance):
    plt.annotate('%0.5f' % avg, xy=(i, avg), color='dodgerblue', xytext=(7, 2), textcoords='offset points')
plt.xlim(-0.1, 2.35) # set xlims to make place for the text
plt.xlabel('Compression Method')
plt.ylabel('Average Distance b/w Uncompressed & Compressed Point')
plt.title('Evaluation of Different Compression Methods - Averages')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: If I copy these lines as they are, I still get an invalid syntax error at ```(f'{avg:0.3}', xy```

Comment: Earlier on, I found a similar method to write exact values for bar charts but I faced the same syntax error on Visual Studio, which is why I shifted to another method

Comment: The syntax error you get with a Python version older than 3.6 Current version is 3.8.   Please try to upgrade. If not, replace the f-string `f'{avg:0.3}'` with `'%0.3f' % avg`.